# What is quantum gate's correponding circuit implementation?

Tags: quantum-gate, random-quantum-circuit

We know that the symbol of a quantum gate like "x gate", "z gate" is an abstraction notation.
For example, the Not-gate in classical computer is composed of 2 transistors.
How can we know quantum gate's exact circuit implementation?

Comment: Hi peachnuts, welcome to QCSE!  This may depend on how the quantum bits (qubits) are implemented, but remember a quantum circuit does not generally abstractly describe *physical* gates, like transistors; rather they are implemented more often as well-timed laser pulses/microwave pulses acting on the qubits. For example, Google's [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-03213-z) on their Sycamore processor - which uses superconducting transmon qubits - goes to some length describing how their gates are implemented with microwave pulses on their qubits.

Comment: Mark S is completely right, but if you're looking to build physical intuition you may want to start with something more elementary than transmons, which make use of [cQED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_quantum_electrodynamics#Artificial_atoms,_Qubits). If you're looking to ease into things, I went through an implementation of a controlled-not gate based on non-linear optics in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/why-does-a-controlled-gate-not-constitute-a-measurement/8521#8521), which is about as simple as quantum gates get.

Comment: I'm afraid this is currently too broad to write a definitive complete answer to, as quite simply, it depends on both the gate and the implementation details, of which there are *many* - if you have a specific physical type of quantum computer in mind (e.g. superconducting transmons), if you [edit] the question to include this info, it can get reopened

Comment: As mentioned above, there are many approaches how to realize quantum computer. I think this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0002077 can help you. It describes general requirements on some system to be a quantum computer.